# Как лучше реализовать ожидание по времени в сервисе

Tags: java, android

Мне нужно что бы сервис раз в 5 минут выполнял определенное действие.
Сейчас я это реализую так:

```
boolean working = true;    
while (working){
           // Дейстие
            try {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(300); //5min
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Это нормальный вариант или лучше использовать что то другое?

Comment: Нет, это не нормальный вариант) Вам надо не держать всё время сервис живущим, а запускать его только в нужное время, тем более, что система рано или поздно ваш сервис прибьёт во имя экономии русурсов. Возьмите лучше `Firebase Job Dispatcher` для запуска задач по рассписанию. Вот тут все доступные варианты описаны: https://habr.com/post/336120/

Answer (score 1):

Пусть следующий класс будет реализацией того, что вы хотите делать каждые пять минут:

```
public class Task implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("I do something...");
        // ...
    }
}
```

Тогда следующий код будет запускать его каждые пять минут:

```
    ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Task(), 0, 5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

Comment: Для службы не особо подходит ибо система спустя минуту бездействия убивает процесс. Это можно решить уменьшив интервал до 30 секунд.

Comment: Какая система и почему эта ваша система не убивает вашу реализацию в вопросе?

Comment: Через некоторое время тестирования заметил что процесс умирает, но решил проблему добавлением START_REDELIVER_INTENT

Answer (score 0):

У меня вот такой код обновляет список каждую минуту (по системным часам):

```
// обновляем список каждую минуту, слушая системные часы

BroadcastReceiver broadcastEveryMinute;

broadcastEveryMinute = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
         if (intent.getAction().compareTo(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK) == 0L)
    // делаешь что нужно, можно подсчитать 5 раз как вариант
    }
};

// регистрируешь слушатель
registerReceiver(broadcastEveryMinute, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK));
```

И останавливаешь когда приложение останавливается:

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (broadcastEveryMinute != null)
        unregisterReceiver(broadcastEveryMinute);
}
```